# Availability of English translations for commentaries of Gautama Dharmasūtra

Tags: translation-request, dharma-shastras

[Gautama Dharmasūtra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Dharmasutra) is a Sanskrit text and likely one of the oldest Hindu Dharmasutras (600-200 BCE), whose manuscripts have survived into the modern age.

From [this](http://scriptures.redzambala.com/dharmasutras/gautama-dharmasutra.html) source

> **There are two extant commentaries on Gautama Dharmasūtra by Maskarin
>   and Haradatta:**
>
> Maskarin can be assigned to – 900–1000 CE and is therefore older than  Haradatta, who also commented on Āpastamba.
>
> It appears that Haradatta has made extensive use of Maskarin’s commentary, a usage that would amount to plagiarism if it was done today.

Are any English translations for those two commentaries available?